# Similar By Terms without vocabulary

Tags: nodes, views, taxonomy-terms

Other modules doing well but not actively developed.

How to make [Similar By Terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms) works without vocabulary?

Comment: Hi, it's hard to tell what your problem is. Instead of asking how to make something "work", you should explain the problem and what you are trying to accomplish. If not, it's impossible to actually answer your question.

Comment: The problem is Similar Entries take too long time to load on my website because too many nodes. My website dont have vocabulary for the nodes. The best way for me is hack Similar By Terms.

Comment: By definition, Similar By Terms cannot work without a vocabulary. The question as it is can have just an answer: no. I agree with @googletorp; you should explain what your problem is, which means the question must be changed. As it is, it is similar to asking "how can I use the taxonomy terms without any node?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider using [Open Calais](http://drupal.org/project/opencalais) or [Auto Tags](http://drupal.org/project/autotagging) to tag all your content. Open Calais will require a little configuration. It works wonderfully with Similar Terms.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at http://drupal.org/project/similar

> A module that displays a block with
>   the most similar nodes to the
>   currently viewed one, based on the
>   title and body fields. Related pages
>   show as a list in a block

I am using it on my own website with good results